# Setting ItemsPanel in Trigger fails to respond to change in theme for WPF ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

The visible items in a listbox do not see changes when the theme changes when I set the ItemsPanel via a trigger. If I scroll the listbox down a few pages and then scroll back up the initial visible items do get updated.

If I set the ItemsPanel directly (see commented out xaml below, and remove the style) the visible items in the listbox do reflect the change in theme
immediately.

Can some one please suggest how to change out an ItemsPanelTemplate and get it to respond to a change in theme?

```
<ListBox
  SelectionMode="Extended"
  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LayerItemTemplateSelector}"
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsView}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMyItem, Mode=TwoWay}">

  <ListBox.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="StackItemsPanelTemplate">
      <VirtualizingStackPanel 
                     Orientation="Vertical" 
                    VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                       IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                     IsVirtualizing="True"
                      />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="WrapItemsPanelTemplate">
      <telerik:VirtualizingWrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

  </ListBox.Resources>

  <!-- THIS WORKS
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel 
                     Orientation="Vertical" 
                    VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                       IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                     IsVirtualizing="True"
                      />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>-->

  <ListBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox"  BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}">
      <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{DynamicResource StackItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsLoadingUnitShowLayerActive, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{DynamicResource StackItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsLoadingUnitHideLayerActive, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{DynamicResource WrapItemsPanelTemplate}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.Style>


  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListBox>
```

Comment: Try adding `IsItemsHost='True'` to both panels in `ItemsPanelTemplate`s.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help.